# GitHub - repository collaborator adding requests

Tags: git, github

Where I can view whom I sent a collaborator request for the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see that under the repo -> Settings -> collaborators. Those that haven't answered should still be on that list.

e.g.

https://github.com/yourUsername/reponame/settings/collaboration